# How do I use the new Server Discover and Monitoring pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor in Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongo-express

I am quite new to docker. I am trying to configure mongodb and mongo-express in the same docker network. I created a network called some-network. Then I ran mongodb with this command to set up mongo in the same network, I ran the command:

```
docker run -d --network some-network --name some-mongo \                    
    -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=mongoadmin \
    -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret \
    mongo
```

However, when I run the command to configure mongo-express, I get an error:

```
docker run --network some-network -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=some-mongo -p 8081:8081 mongo-express
Welcome to mongo-express
------------------------


(node:7) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
(node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: command listDatabases requires authentication
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:453:61)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at processMessage (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:456:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:625:15)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
(node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Am I missing anything?, How do I use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor in docker?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't tell what the problem was but running these commands fixed the issue

To set up mongodb

```
docker run --network some-network -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=some-mongo -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=mongoadmin -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=secret -p 8081:8081 mongo-express
```

And then mongo-express:

```
Docker run --name mongo-express --network some-network -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=some-mongo -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=mongoadmin -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=secret -p 8081:8081 mongo-express
```

Comment: Would you mind looking over the answer again? It's basically twice the same command (except for the command docker/Docker).